# What do I get an error when I attempt to connect a vue component to my router.js file?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, auth0

I have created my auth0 configuration and I am now importing my login page

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'


Vue.use(Router)


// create import statements
import login from './containers/login'
import home from './containers/home'
import dashboard from './containers/dashboard'
import projects from './containers/projects'
import auth from './auth'


// application routes

const routes = [

// each path will render each component when it experiences an event

{ path: '/', component: home },
{ path: '/dashboard', component: dashboard },
{ path: '/projects', component: projects }

]


// export router instance

/* Using mode : 'history '
This removes the hash from the url and gives
the app a cleaner url string
*/


export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes,

/* use link activeClass to indicate what
class to add to the navigation to make the menu item active

*/


  linkActiveClass: 'is-active'
})
```

I am running into this error though

```
Syntax Error: import is a reserved word (32:2)
```

Before the login.vue and auth.js was added the code was functional, but when I enter those it returns the above error.

I am using vue.js framework, and Auth0 for security.

Comment: Why do you want to import auth.js when you are not usind it?

Answer (score 0):

Import is a keyword in ES2016 which is a new JavaScript standard. To me it looks like you're using ES5, which is the version currently available in most browsers. To use ES6 features you need to transpile your code to ES5 using a tool such as Babel. If you created your project with vue-cli according to the tutorials, Babel should be automatically configured on your project.